# HTML output has extra breaks

Tags: python, html

Below is how outlook displays the email that I wanted to send. If you notice there is an extra break at the bottom of the `Title1` table. I don't quite understand why that exists.

```
   [Paragraph Here]

========================== Title1 ==========================
      Spot      Track    Quality      Combo       Fast
         1          8        218        218        287
         2       2873         58       2877       2935
         3         15        215        215        287
         4        412         52        419        476
         5         16        223        223        282
         6        103         85        139        276

====================================
 ========================
========================= Title2 ==========================
      Spot      Track    Quality      Combo       Fast
         1         69       1956       1958       2514
         2       7339        450       7373       7927
         3        114       1916       1916       2524
         4       3651        465       3669       4017
         5        102       1956       1956       2532
         6       1546        614       1763       2604

============================================================
```

I am using `smtplib`, `MIMEText`, and `MIMEMultipart` to send the email with HTML. I create a formatted text string by concatenating different strings together from a python code here:

```py
text = """[Paragraph] \n\n\n\n"""

text += f"{' Title1 ':=^60}\n"
for i in range(6):
    track   = ~flags_outside[f'las{i+5}_trackf'].astype(bool)
    qual    = flags_outside[f'las{i+5}_qualf'].astype(bool)
    combo   = np.logical_or(track,qual)
    fast    = out_arr_outside[:,i]

    nfast   = np.sum(fast)
    ntrack  = np.sum(track)
    nqual   = np.sum(qual)
    ncombo  = np.sum(combo)

    if i == 0:
        text += f"{'Spot':>10s} {'Track':>10s} {'Quality':>10s} {'Combo':>10s} {'Fast':>10s}\n"

    text += f"{i+1:>10d} {ntrack:>10d} {nqual:>10d} {ncombo:>10d} {nfast:>10d}\n"

text += "="*60 + "\n"

text += f"{' Title2 ':=^60}\n"
for i in range(6):
    track   = ~flags[f'las{i+5}_trackf'].astype(bool)
    qual    = flags[f'las{i+5}_qualf'].astype(bool)
    combo   = np.logical_or(track,qual)
    fast    = out_arr[:,i]

    nfast   = np.sum(fast)
    ntrack  = np.sum(track)
    nqual   = np.sum(qual)
    ncombo  = np.sum(combo)

    if i == 0:
        text += f"{'Spot':>10s} {'Track':>10s} {'Quality':>10s} {'Combo':>10s} {'Fast':>10s}\n"

    text += f"{i+1:>10d} {ntrack:>10d} {nqual:>10d} {ncombo:>10d} {nfast:>10d}\n"

text += "="*60 + "\n"
```

Then to use HTML `<br>` instead of `\n` I perform a `text.replace("\n","<br>")` and wrap said `text` like so:

```py
html = """<pre><font face='monospace'>""" + text + """</font></pre>"""
```

Can someone explain why the extra break occurs? Am I doing something bad with the HTML syntax or something else like using too many line break elements when I replace `\n` with `<br>` in the text string?

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not using `<table>`?

Comment: No reason other than I don't use HTML all that much so I didn't know that was an element to use

Comment: I don't see anything in your code that would create that line break. `"="*60 + "\n"` should create 60 consecutive `=` characters. Something else is doing it, maybe the SMTP library

Comment: In that case, why are you using HTML at all? Just send plain text email.

Comment: I needed the HTML to send monospaced text otherwise the lines don't align